# Why does this error appear when i try to run my react app?

Tags: reactjs, npm, config

I am trying to run my react app and i keep getting this error :
configFactory is not a function
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! purple-react-free@1.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!

I tried updating node but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

have you installed all dependencies for the project?

```
npm install
```

If you have so, I strongly recommend that you delele your node-modules folder, and clean the node cache with `npm cache clean --force` and then try to run the npm install again.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Yes I have tried this, I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade react-scripts to solve this